# Validation in VB6

Tags: validation, vb6

I need help in validation in VB6, where it will check if the user type-in www. on a text-box, because I wanted to make the www. static

```
Dim Text As String
Text = Text1.Text
If Text1.Text = "www." Then
MsgBox "www. is already present", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Opps!..."
ElseIf Text1.Text = "WWW." Then
MsgBox "www. is already present", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Opps!..."
Else
Open ("C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts") For Append As #1
Print #1, "127.0.0.1     " + "www." + Text
Close #1
End If
```

This seems to be not working because the msgbox will only appear when a user just type in "www." But I want to make it like when the user type www. the message-box will appear.

Comment: Why not just add it automatically if it doesn't exist? Also, not all website addresses, let alone hostnames start with `www.`.

Comment: yes it adds automatically with 

Print #1, "127.0.0.1     " + "www." + Text

thing is what if the user wants to type in, www.<insertword> then it will become, www.www.<insertword> thats why i wanted a msgbox that will stop that from executing.

Comment: you missed my point. not all website addresses start with `www.`. If you forcible prepend it, the address won't match. It also means the `hosts` entry can be bypassed just by removing the `www.` from the address entered in the web browser.

Comment: with that, ill just add combo-box or drop downlist to list down the possible starting web address, better yet thanks for your answer it helps me.

Comment: All possible? Why not just let them enter a name? If you want to catch `www.` as well, add two entries. what will it do with `hashvb.earlsoft.co.uk`? `mail.example.com`? `mycameras.mydomain.com`? None of which work or even resolve with a `www.` prefix.

Comment: We dont use that here in my country. normally were just using domains using www. so yeah, thanks again its been a help. and im just starting out with programming so please dont bombard me.

Comment: What you use in your country is irrelevant. The internet is global. Other hostnames exist. your software will not work with them. Also, if you're new, it's a good idea to take advice from people that know better :)

Comment: It feels like im being scolded because of those details but anyway, ill just follow what youve said thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, truth and reality of programming :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use the `Left$()` function.

```
If StrComp(Left(Text1.Text, 4), "www.", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
  ...
```

The `StrComp()` with `vbTextCompare` makes it case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother to user to check the data, just remove the www. like this:  replace(text1.text ,"www.","",,,vbTextCompare)      Not matter if the test is upper or lower case.